# httprc:request throws exception exit: {noproc, {gen_server,call, [httpc_manager ...]}}

Tags: erlang, httpc

I want to invoke `httprc:request` in my erlang program, but I get an exception, which has no information to me, what went wrong.

This is my code:

```
print_helloworld() ->
  Body = "userId=12345",
  httpc:request(post,
    {
    "'http://192.168.2.100:8080/010/xmppcontrol", [],
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      Body
    }, [], []).
```

This is my exception:

```
1> hello_world:print_helloworld().
** exception exit: {noproc,
                    {gen_server,call,
                     [httpc_manager,
                      {request,
                       {request,undefined,<0.58.0>,0,'\'http',
                        {"192.168.2.100",8080},
                        "/010/xmppcontrol",[],post,
                        {http_request_h,undefined,"keep-alive",undefined,
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                         undefined,...},
                        {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","userId=12345"},
                        {http_options,"HTTP/1.1",infinity,true,
                         {essl,[]},
                         undefined,false,infinity,...},
                        "'http://192.168.2.100:8080/010/xmppcontrol",[],none,
                        [],1510504662776,undefined,undefined,false}},
                      infinity]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/3 (gen_server.erl, line 214)
     in call from httpc:handle_request/9 (httpc.erl, line 554)
```

Can you tell what is wrong in the `httpc:request` call, because when I call the URL from JS, it works fine.

This is my code from JavaScript:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", stateChange, false);
asyncRequest.open('POST', 'http://192.168.2.100:8080/010/xmppcontrol?userId=' + userId , true);
asyncRequest.send(null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says that there's no process running that is bound to the name `httpc_manager`. As documented in [`httpc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) and [`inets`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html), you need to have the `inets`  application running to make httpc requests work. You can do this either by adding the application to the applications list when using rebar (in `src/....app.src`) or starting the `inets` application manually, e.g.

```
inets:start(),
httpc:request(...).
```

Comment: I get no errors, but my servlet don´t gets executed, or is the httpc call in a wrong format to reach the servlet?

Comment: You also have an extra single quote at the start of the URL. Can you try removing that?

Comment: Oh, I´m sorry, didn´t see it. Now it´s working fine. Thank you :)